# Autotest not testing

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration, autotest

Autotest doesn't seem to be working for me.  I've installed what seem to be all the dependencies. When I make changes in my code, or force failures in tests, nothing happens while running autotest.

When I run autotest either just as 'autotest' or 'bundle exec autotest' I see the following:

```
(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.) 
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
```

Here is the excerpt from my GemFile:

```
gem "rspec-rails"
gem "cucumber-rails"
gem "webrat"
gem 'ZenTest'
gem 'test_notifier'
gem 'autotest'
gem 'autotest-rails'
gem 'autotest-fsevent'
gem 'autotest-growl'
gem 'redgreen'
```

The following is my discover.rb:

```
Autotest.add_discovery { "rails" }
Autotest.add_discovery { "rspec2" }
```

I'm on rails 3.0.0, ruby 1.8.7

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This just happened to me when I had some specs in /spec directory. Once I moved them to /specs/models they worked.

Answer (score 0):

there have been a few updates to rspec2 lately with regards to autotest checkout the latest release and release notes